_vlcViewController.startRecording not working
I have a startRecording function which uses flutter_vlc_player package. The function will start recording the video displayed in the VLC player.
Future\<void\> startRecording() async {
bool recordingStarted = false;
final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
setState(() {
recording = true;
// final timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
saveDirectory = '${directory.path}/recordings/';
logger.i('saveDirectory: $saveDirectory');
});

    final saveDir = Directory(saveDirectory);
    await saveDir.create();
    
    final result = await _vlcViewController.startRecording(
      saveDirectory,
    );
    recordingStarted = result ?? false;
    
    if (recordingStarted) {
      logger.i('Recording started: $recordingStarted');
    } else {
      logger.w('Recording have not started');
    }
}

and in my stopRecording,

Future\<void\> stopRecording() async {
setState(() {
recording = false;
});
final recordingStopped = await \_vlcViewController.stopRecording();
print("recordingStopped $recordingStopped");
if (recordingStopped != null && recordingStopped) {
final recordedPath = await \_vlcViewController.value.recordPath;
logger.i('Recording stopped: $recordingStopped');
final saveDirectoryFileExists = await File(recordedPath).exists();
logger.i("saveDirectoryFileExists: $saveDirectoryFileExists");

      final futures = await Future.wait([
        File(saveDirectory).exists(),
        File("/storage/emulated/0/$saveDirectory").exists(),
        File("/sdcard/$saveDirectory").exists(),
      ]);
      print("saveDirectory $saveDirectory");
      for (var element in futures) {
        logger.i("element: $element");
      }
    } else {
      logger.w('Recording have not stopped');
    }

}

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
\_vlcViewController = VlcPlayerController.network(
stockSourceUrl, // droneSourceUrl,
autoPlay: true,
autoInitialize: true,
hwAcc: HwAcc.full,
options: VlcPlayerOptions(),
);

I tried using the flutter_vlc_player package for recording a live video stream. In my startRecording, I initialize first the saveDirectory string path using getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() function. Then, inside the path, I created the recordings folder where _vlcViewController.startRecording() should saved the random file after recording. But when I checked the directory in my device, the recording folder is empty which means that it did not save the file. I also tried printing the result variable and it prints true. To further test, in my stopRecording, I tried to print the recorded video using _vlcViewController.value.recordPath() but it prints empty. Do you have an idea why the _vlcViewController.startRecording() was not able to create the file? Furthermore, I tried to use the _vlcViewController.takeSnapshot() and printed the result and it prints the frame value.
